# show color shades in between range of percentage

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How can we show color shades in between range of percentage.Here I am trying to design different colors of shades and show range number in percentage.How can we do this please guide me.

here is the example like what I am trying to design and show colors shades.
[image: color shades range]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rgba color property to adjust the alpha level of any color.

For example in your case the darkest color has R:36, G: 89, B: 137

So the rgba color code for the 80-100% range will be `rgba(36,89,137,1)` and the lightest color code for the 0-20% range can be `rgba(36,89,137,0.20)`

Answer (score 0):

I think a good approach could be to use the hsl color system (Hue, Saturation, Lightness).

For example you go with a fix Hue, let's say 230deg, and a fixed Saturation, let's say 70%. Then you can change the Lightness and you will easiliy get different intensities of a same color.

You can obviously try to also change the Saturation to fit to your need.

These colors can then be easily used in your `css` rules, for example `background-color: hsl(230, 70%, 50%);`

A great tool to do this is this link [Color HSL](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_hsl.asp)